# How to stay in the directory after subshell completion?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to do this (just an example, not a real life situation):

```
$ mkdir test; ( cd test; echo "foo" > test.txt ); cat test.txt
cat: test.txt: No such file or directory
```

However, it fails, since `cd test` directory change is reverted after subshell is finished. What is a workaround? I can't use script `.sh` files, everything should be in one command line.

Comment: "`cd test` directory change is reverted after subshell is finished." Take it out of the subshell.

Comment: It has to be inside the subshell. I'm changing the directory in the subshell, and want to preserve this change when subshell is finished.

Comment: so, you should not know the mkdir test command?

Comment: Then you have to change directory outside when the subshell is finished. A subshell cannot change its parent's working directory. Period.

Comment: You would probably get better and more applicable answers if you tell us the actual problem.

Comment: how about define a var in beginning, like a=test; mkdir $a; ... ; cat $a/test.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skip the subshell and use a `{ ... }` block instead (or explain your usecase, since this example does not make so much sense):

```
$ find
.
$ mkdir dir; { cd dir; echo foo > test.txt; }; cat test.txt
foo
$ cd ..
$ find
.
./dir
./dir/test.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Maybe you know the answer to this related one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513631/why-pipe-resets-current-working-directory

Comment: @yegor256 Yes, as stated in the answers over there, the pipe creates a subshell.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just?

```
mkdir test; echo "foo" > test/test.txt; cat test/test.txt
```

Another way is

```
mkdir test; cd "$(cd test; echo "foo" > test.txt; echo "$PWD";)"; cat test.txt
```

Or

```
mkdir test; (cd test; echo "foo" > test.txt; echo "$PWD" > /some/file); cd "$(</some/file)"; cat test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

As commenters have said, a child process can't modify the parent's working directory. You can return a value from the child process for the parent to read, then make the parent act on this value. Meaningless `bash` example:-

```
$ mkdir test; DIR=$( cd test; echo "foo" > test.txt; echo test ); cat $DIR/test.txt
```